# How to decompress a FileStorage object over gzip in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, httprequest, gzip, file-storage

I am sending a compressed file (compressed with gzip) to my flask application over an HTTP multipart/form-data POST request. The request works correctly and when I print out the value of the key to the console it prints this: `<FileStorage: 'compressed.zip' ('application/zip')>`. This was compressed using Windows zip compressed but will be compressed using the `application/gzip` type. The key for the compressed.zip file is called `compressed`. My question is how can I decompress the gzip file and then store the FileStorage object to a specific path on the backend? Here is the code that I have currently:

```
from flask import request, Blueprint, make_response
import gzip
blueprint = Blueprint("blueprint", __name__)

@blueprint.route("/compressed-post", methods=["POST"])
def compressed_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["compressed"]
        print(file)
        return make_response("", 200)
    else:
        return make_response("", 400)
```

Comment: So you want to decompress the gzip file and put the contents (all of the files in the compressed file) in a filestorage?

Comment: yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: I am going to upload an answer soon. So just put all the files who are in the zip file in some folder and `file` contains the compressed file right?

Comment: Yes pretty much, but also as I mentioned before, `file` is a FileStorage object so I dont know how to do this with that data type.

Comment: @Patch are you going to upload an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code snippet...

```
@blueprint.route("/compressed-post", methods=["POST"])
def compressed_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["compressed"]
```

... you just have to pass in `file._file` into a `ZipFile` constructor, as `ZipFile` expects a file-like-object (or a complete path, which we do not have here, as the file was not yet saved to disk).

Then, you can use `ZipFile`s `extractAll` method to extract the files to a path you like.

Also see

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall

So, the complete code should something like this:

```
from flask import request, Blueprint, make_response
import gzip
from zipfile import ZipFile
blueprint = Blueprint("blueprint", __name__)

@blueprint.route("/compressed-post", methods=["POST"])
def compressed_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["compressed"]
        zip_handle = ZipFile(file._file)
        zip_handle.extractall(CHOOSE_YOUR_PATH)
        zip_handle.close()
        return make_response("", 200)
    else:
        return make_response("", 400)
```

`ZipFile` also has a contextmanager, if you prefer the `with` syntax.

A word of caution: the `_` in `file._file` indicates, that `_file` is not part of the public interface, and may change in future.

Comment: I'll try this solution out shortly. I am confused though by what you said about the `_` in `_file`. What does that mean that it's not part of the public interface and what sort of issues could using `_file` create?

Comment: This is hard to explain in a comment. Usually, authors of libraries make sure, not to change variable and function names, which the user of the library will use. e.g. the name ZipFile won't be changed easily, as many rely on this name to stay the same. This does not apply for names starting with an underscore. While you can also use them, like here `_file`, the author of the library may change it without a "bad" feeling, as an underscore is an indicator for "please do not use". Don't worry too much! I am pretty confident there won't be a change in the next years.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. Developers usually state any changes to an open-source library they created in a changelog correct? If they have documentation (for which I hope they do) then they would state the changes made so currently, this is not a big issue. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
from flask import request, Blueprint, make_response
from zipfile import ZipFile
import gzip
blueprint = Blueprint("blueprint", __name__)

@blueprint.route("/compressed-post", methods=["POST"])
def compressed_post():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["compressed"]
        print(file)
        file_name = file.filename
        with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip: 
            # printing all the contents of the zip file 
            zip.printdir() 
  
            # extracting all the files 
            print('Extracting all the files now...') 
            zip.extractall(<path_to_destination_dir>) 
            print('Done!')
        
        return make_response("", 200)
    else:
        return make_response("", 400)
```

See this for more details on zip: [ZipFile](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-zip-files-python/) and [extractall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall)

See this for more details on FileStorage Object: [FileStorage](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.14.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)

Incase you need more info to store FileStorage object:
Save the file to a destination path or file object. If the destination is a file object you have to close it yourself after the call. The buffer size is the number of bytes held in memory during the copy process. It defaults to 16KB.

See this: [save](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.html#:%7E:text=The%20FileStorage%20class%20is%20a,of%20the%20long%20form%20storage.)

I hope it helps.

Comment: For the save() function, what if I don't know the buffer size, assuming it is bigger than the default 16KB? I don't want to overflow the buffer if that vulnerability is possible.

Comment: Also, I used your code exactly and getting a FileNotFoundError with the `file_name` variable on the response from this line of code `with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:`.

Comment: Do you know why I am getting this error? I am not able to save the file with the `save()` function since it's a zip file, so that's probably why the error is being thrown since it's not saved in the current directory, so how can I go about fixing this?

Comment: This cannot work, as `filen_ame` is just a the filename, and not the complete path. For one of the several possible solutions, see my answer.